# Converting Code from Teradata to HIVE Rank Order

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions

I need help with converting the below query from syntax appropriate for teradata to HIVE.

I've tried a copy and past for the subquery but I'm not able to get the qualify clause to work.

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Month_Shifts AS (
    SELECT "Month"
        , Emp_ID
        , Emp_NM
        , MAX(ending_team) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY "Month" ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Starting_team
        , ending_team
    FROM
        (
            SELECT "Month"
                , Emp_id
                , current_team AS Ending_team
                , COUNT(DISTINCT call_key) AS CallVolume
            FROM data
            GROUP BY 1,2,3
            QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "month", Emp_ID, Emp_NM ORDER BY CallVolume DESC) = 1
        ) a
    ) WITH DATA NO PRIMARY INDEX ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

It should be able to run without issue. Currently seeing this error message:
FAILED: ParseException line 1:260 missing EOF at 'QUALIFY' near '4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive, you can just move the condition to the outer query:

```
SELECT "Month", Emp_ID, Emp_NM,
       LAG(ending_team) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY "Month") AS Starting_team,
       ending_team
FROM (SELECT d."month", d.Emp_ID, d.Emp_NM,
             current_team AS Ending_team,
             COUNT(DISTINCT call_key) AS CallVolume,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "month", Emp_ID, Emp_NM ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT call_key) DESC) as seqnum
        FROM data d
        GROUP d."month", d.Emp_ID, d.Emp_NM
    ) d
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- The `QUALIFY` is replaced by the `WHERE` in the outer query.
- Do not use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  List the columns.  Regardless of database.
- Hive supports `LAG()`, which is more appropriate for the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: A few questions: I'm confused at the use of the 'd' reference in the subquery given it isn't defined till the outer query. Does hive review the query holistically, thus understands the reference? If so, why doesn't the outer query need the preface? Since no joins are occurring, why is the db name necessary at all?

Comment: In the subquery, I think the "ending team" column is missing. I  see referenced it in the outer query but didn't select it initially. How would I rectify that?